# Is there a jQuery event listener for jQuery's .load();?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to run a `$(document).ready();` type of function when a `div` element loads, but it should run after I use jQuery's `.load()`.

I'm making a website where I want to navigate between pages by having a container where my page is loaded. When I load a page, I say `myContainer.empty();` to clear it, and then I have a separate html file which contains the html for the other page, so then I just say `myContainer.load('myOtherPage.html');`. This works perfectly, but I need an event listener to run when a certain page gets loaded into `myContainer`.

I use:

```
myPageContainer.empty();
myPageContainer.load('home.html');
```

but, my javascript doesn't pick up the fact that it loaded, and I have some events that need firing when the page gets loaded.

So, in short, I basically need a type of event listener that runs when my page gets loaded via jQuery's `.load();`.

Comment: Is a callback, that is executed once load has run enough for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#success").load("somefile.html", function(response, status, xhr){
  if(status == "error"){
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
```

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

[image]

@Sebastian's comment :

```
if (myPageContainer.addEventListener) {
  myPageContainer.addEventListener('load', function() {
       /* do stuff */ 
  });
} else {
  // it's IE!
  myPageContainer.attachEvent('load', function() {
    /* do stuff */
  });
}
```

Hope this works for you?

Comment: Thanks @Jaapaap, but I need a way to listen for the load on another js file.

Comment: call that function defined in another js file from the callback.

Comment: In the example shown above the function will fire once the load() completes, from there you can do anything you need, does not matter what js file the code you then want to run is in, so long as the files with that have been loaded by then (which if they are included in the html you are loading in load(), or included in the original page, they should be).