# Get child count after loading content

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, load

I have in my index page a DIV called "container" and a bunch of articles ("article") in external html page named articles.html, i want to load the content of articles.html to "container" div in my index page and after loading get their count so i proceded like this :

```
<div id="container">
    <button onclick="getchildkount()">Childs count</button>
</div>

<script>
$('#container').load('articles.html');
let cc=document.getElementById("container").childElementCount;
alert(cc);
</script>
```

And in my articles.html page i have like :

```
<div class="article">
    **********
    ********** etc.
</div>
<div class="article">
    **********
    ********** etc.
</div>
<div class="article">
    **********
    ********** etc.
</div>
```

So basically my content will be loaded with the three articles in the "container" div but the count will be alerted as 0, i know it's due to the asynchronous way JS operate because when i add a function :

```
function getchildkount(){
    let numb = document.getElementById("necroContainer").childElementCount;
    alert(numb);
}
```

and call it from button onclick event after everything is loaded it show me "3" in the alert message.

I want to wait for the load to complete to get child count automatically without rely on the button onclick so i can use the variable further, as a begineer i don't know what the best way to deal with this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: please search before asking a question https://stackoverflow.com/a/54041238/9677706

Comment: @PoryaGrand i already searched but as i mentionned as a beginner i need to improve my keywords search, ... so i tried and it's works, can you post this as an answer so i can accept it ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

based on
[Is there a jQuery event listener for jQuery's .load();?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041136/is-there-a-jquery-event-listener-for-jquerys-load/54041238#54041238)

the function `load` has a second argument that is a callback function. it fires when an error occures or it succeed.

```js
$("#success").load("somefile.html", function(response, status, xhr){
  if(status == "error"){
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
```